# how to obtain prediction accuracy in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I try predicting "cyl" in the "mtcars" data with "cyl" as a factor variable:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
```

I split the dataset to "training" and "testing":

```
inTrain = inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=mtcars$cyl,p=0.75, list=FALSE)
training = mtcars[ inTrain,]
testing = mtcars[-inTrain,]
```

and fit a random forests model:

```
modelRF <- train(cyl ~ .,method="rf",data=training)
predRF <- predict(modelRF,testing)
```

Currently I try obtaining prediction accuracy with confusionMatrix function:

```
confusionMatrix(testing$cyl, predict(predRF, newdata = testing))
```

...but I keep getting this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is there any better method for obtaining prediction accuracy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be a bit confused. `predRF` already *is* a prediction by definition - it is not something you can meaningfully feed into `predict()`. Therefore, you will get your confusion matrix simply as follows:

```
> confusionMatrix(testing$cyl,predRF)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction 4 6 8
         4 2 0 0
         6 0 1 0
         8 0 0 3
```

In addition, a line starting `inTrain = inTrain <-` looks a bit strange, though syntactically valid. I strongly suggest you look closely at your code, as I suspect there may be a few more errors hidden there.